# How to set random max that the user choose

Tags: java, android, android-activity, random

I'm trying to write simple code that allows the user to chose max number for random commend in one activity and use it in another activity. (The min is 1)

I succeeded to call the int variable from activity A to activity B but when I try to use it in the random commend the app crashes.

Here I call for the int:

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
highNum = intent.getIntExtra("highNum", 0);
```

And put in the random:

```
Random random = new Random();
mainNum = random.nextInt(highNum) + 1;
```

I already checked that the int really equals to a number higher than the defualt - 0.

Here is what I thick is the important part of the stack flow:

> ```
> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: n <= 0: 0
> at java.util.Random.nextInt(Random.java:182)
> at com.appstudio.shirdn.sevenboom.MainActivity.randomNumber(MainActivity.java:148)
> at com.appstudio.shirdn.sevenboom.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:40)
> ```

Line 148 is where I set `mainNum`, and line 40 is on the `onCreate`
 class where I call for the random class.

Thank you!

Comment: What is the stack trace of the crash?  That is always important to know.

Comment: where do you put the extra `"highNum"` in Activity-A ?

Answer (score 0):

The stack trace is telling you that the number you passed into `Random.nextInt()` is actually 0.  Here are its actual lines of code from the Android platform API level 23:

```
public int nextInt(int n) {
    if (n <= 0) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("n <= 0: " + n);
    }
    ...
}
```

You can see that the message is inserting the value of n into the exception error message.  This corresponds to the value of your highNum.

Check your value of highNum just before it's being passed into this method.

Answer (score 0):

This exception is because **you are trying to generate a random number but you are not validating the *bound*** passed as parameter**:

here:

```
mainNum = random.nextInt(highNum) + 1;
```

it happens to be that the variable **highNum** must be positive

Solution:

validate the variable highNum before passing its value to the nextInt method:

do something as simple as:

```
if (highNum > 0) {
    mainNum = random.nextInt(highNum) + 1;
}
```

If you need it, take a look to the official [Documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextInt()):

> **Parameters**:   bound the upper bound (exclusive). Must be positive.